# Add required true and render in template

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have in schema.yml:

```
Quest:
  columns:
    yes_no:  { type: boolean, notnull: true }
    answer:   { type: string(100), notnull: false }
```

and QuestForm

```
$this->widgetSchema['yes_no'] = new sfWidgetFormSelectRadio(array('choices' => array(1 => 'yes', 0 => 'no')));
```

In template `default` I would like to render only this widget on start, but if user checks "no", then I would like to render widget **answer** also, with textbox and this must be `required => true`, not null. 
What is the best way to make it?

Comment: When the user checks "no", the form is already rendered, so it's too late to say you want to render the answer widget too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony-like, this is achieved with a PostValidator !

First, as @samura mentioned, hide and observe the answer widget via (e.g.) jQuery, then use a PostValidator.

```
// Form.class.php
/* ..... */
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
    new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'checkAnswer')))
);
```

Then implement your validator

```
// Form.class.php something else
public function checkAnswer($validator, $values)
{
   if (($values['yes_no'] == '0') && (empty($values['answer')))
   {
       $error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Invalid answer');

       // throw answer error
       throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('answer' => $error));
   }

   return $values;
}
```

You can find more [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/conditional-validator)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the first part with jquery - observe the `yes_no` field for changes and show/hide the `answer` field.
Then with a custom validator you can do the testing you need.

Comment: how can i make these validator?